# Is there a shortcut for rotating the screen in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: macos, display, osx-yosemite

Is there a shortcut for rotating the screen in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?
If there is not a default shortcut, is there a way to assign one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly decent question. But there doesn’t seem to be a clean/off-the-shelf answer.

I found [these AppleScripts (RotateDisplayScripts.zip)](http://www.gizmometer.com/software/freeware/RotateDisplayScripts.zip) via this [*Mac OS X Hints* thread](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071003040156502) that supposedly allow one to rotate screens via AppleScript (obviously) but I could not get them to work. Note that to get it to initially work, you need to go into “Security & Privacy” select the “Privacy” tab and then under “Accessibility” add *AppleScript Editor* to the list of apps that can control your computer; screenshot below. But like I said, even after that was done, they did not seem to work on my Intel-based Mac Mini:

[image]

And I found [*EasyPivot*](http://filiptepper.github.io/2011/03/10/easypivot-on-the-mac-app-store/) which seems to do exactly what you are looking for. That said, it *was* in the Apple App store at one point but now has been pulled by the author due to “…many issues with Apple APIs…” and such with [no plans on re-releasing the app](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/filiptepper-com/easypivot_on_the_mac_app_store_filip_tepper/).

Answer (score 1):

Hacked together a good enough solution using applescript that works on OS El Capitan (10.11.6) so YMMV. It's easy to kick it off with Quicksilver directly or via a Quicksilver trigger and takes about the amount of time it takes to physically rotate and adjust a monitor. Hope this helps someone!

This applescript switches the target display "DELL U2414H" to portrait mode with 270 degrees rotation. Note that the string "DELL U2414H" is from the window title representing said display under System Preferences > Displays. Not sure what would happen if it's run when there are two displays of the same make and model – feel free to report findings. Easy potential improvements would be to make it check state and toggle between the two most frequent orientations, but scarcity in time and documentation meant it was good enough for my use case as is. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    delay 1
    click UI element "Displays" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences" of application process "System Preferences"

    delay 1
    click window "DELL U2414H" of application process "System Preferences"

    delay 1
    click pop up button 2 of tab group 1 of window "DELL U2414H" of application process "System Preferences"

    -- select 270° for portrait, for landscape replace 4 with "Standard" (with quotes)
    delay 1
    click menu item 4 of menu 1 of pop up button 2 of tab group 1 of window "DELL U2414H" of application process "System Preferences"

    -- click the "Confirm" button, not necessary for "Standard" orientation
    delay 5
    click UI element "Confirm" of sheet 1 of window "DELL U2414H" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell

tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  You are posting to a very old question and it doesn't appear to address the question in a useful manner as your answer is for a different OS than the question.  You will find that you will have a better experience if you take moment to take the Stack Overflow [tour].  If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: I disagree with Rey Juna and appreciate your answer codeanpeace